# How do I convert a JavaScript event handler inline in HTML to be parameterized?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Quick JavaScript question. I am creating a simple script where a form field entry disappears/reappears using `onfocus` and `onblur`.

I'm wondering why the following inline script works:

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Requires validation"
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Requires validation'){this.value = '';}"
onblur="formappear()">
</div>
```

and the following script with a parameterized function doesn't:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function formclear(field) {

if (field.value == "Requires validation") {
field.value = "";
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Requires validation"
onfocus="formclear(this.id)" onblur="formappear()">
</div>
</body>
```

I appreciate any responses in advance, I'm sure it's a simple mistake I'm making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont pass in `this.id`, just pass in `this`

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Requires validation" onfocus="formclear(this)" onblur="formappear()">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/se6wm/

You were passing in the `id` of the input, so when you were using `field.value` it was actually trying to do `email.value` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, dumb mistake, but I'm always learning. I'll accept the answer when I'm able to.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing in the `id` instead of the `this`

Answer (score 0):

pass a value as  `formclear(this)` instead of `formclear(this.id)`

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Requires validation"
onfocus="formclear(this)" onblur="formappear()">
```